# Swift 5: The given data was not valid JSON (Loading Data from API to Table View)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api

I'm trying to GET some data from an API. It fetches the data fine when I connect the function to an IBAction, but it doesn't work when I execute it at viewDidLoad() as a normal function.

I was hoping to generate it as the app loads up so that I can display them to a table view instead of having to click a button in order to load it every time.

I get an error of "The given data was not valid JSON" after attempting to execute the function from viewDidLoad()

Below are the codes for reference:

```
struct Claims: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let submission_date: String
    let status: String
    init(json: [String:Any]) {
        id = json["id"] as? Int ?? -1
        submission_date = json["submission_date"] as? String ?? ""
        status = json["status"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}

class DashboardController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    var claimSummaryArray: [ClaimProperties] = []
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        getData()
    }

    func getData() {
        guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://claim.ademo.work/claims/") else { return }
        var requestAPI = URLRequest(url: urlString)

        requestAPI.httpMethod = "GET"
        requestAPI.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        requestAPI.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        requestAPI.setValue("Bearer \(appDelegate.userAppToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestAPI) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Claims].self, from: data)
                    print (json)
                } catch let error {
                    print("Seems to have an error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Data variable that is returned (performed via IBAction / clicking a button):

```
[ClaimApp.Claims(id: 1, submission_date: "2020-02-28T13:50:41.000+08:00", status: "pending"), ClaimApp.Claims(id: 2, submission_date: "2020-02-28T13:53:38.000+08:00", status: "pending"), ClaimApp.Claims(id: 3, submission_date: "2020-02-28T14:21:46.000+08:00", status: "pending"), ClaimApp.Claims(id: 4, submission_date: "2020-02-28T14:22:07.000+08:00", status: "pending")]
```

Error that is returned (performed via calling a normal function from viewDidLoad()):

```
Seems to have an error: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))
```

P.S/ I'm new here, apologies if there are any misunderstanding or confusion.

Comment: Can you share an example of the `data` variable that is returned? You can also validate the response here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to see if there are any issues with the tree

Comment: Hi Harry, I've added in the returned data to the question for your reference. I've tried the link you provided as well, the JSON data is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `appToken` is invalid when `viewDidLoad` run. I see your controller is Dashboard and you get token from file so have you read it async? So you should check token have already set on `appDelegate` before `DashboardController` call `viewDidLoad`. Let debug or print log to see what coming first.

If token have set after `DashboardController` call `viewDidLoad` i think you need do some loading before call that controller.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks! You are right, the userAppToken was invalid. I had to call a function from the app delegate file and pass the value over to the dashboard controller. Previously with IBAction, I passed the value into that function. But I cut and pasted the whole thing into viewDidLoad() without declaring what userAppToken was. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the **viewDidLoad** whether you are getting value for **userAppToken** in below line that might expired, caused to be an issue

```
func getData() {
        guard let urlString = URL(string: "https://claim.ademo.work/claims/") else { return }
        var requestAPI = URLRequest(url: urlString)

        requestAPI.httpMethod = "GET"
        requestAPI.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        requestAPI.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        requestAPI.setValue("Bearer \("appDelegate.userAppToken")", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestAPI) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                    print(str) // this is giving message HTTP Token: Access denied.
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Claims].self, from: data)
                    print (json)
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    print("Seems to have an error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ajay, I get userAppToken from the App Delegate swift file upon user login via Google API. I forgot to add that part into the question, my apologies. I've amended from userAppToken to appDelegate.userAppToken in the question.

Comment: @ShaniceChan print response getting in data you might find your issue like in do block of request convert data into string like  
let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
print(str)

Comment: Hi Ajay, the issue was with the token declaration. Thanks for your help!